# Drools: AfterMatchFiringEvent triggering multiple times for the same rule with OR conditions?

Tags: java, drools, rule-engine, kie

I'm using the following structure in my DrL file built using RuleDescrBuilder APIs provided with the org.drools.compiler.lang.api.

I trigger an after match event to keep track of number of hits for each rule in the backend. However, when the input(Predicate) matches all the given conditions in Rule1, it's triggering multiple afterMatchFiredEvents for one input.

```
import com.objects.Predicate

global com.Util policyUtil

dialect "java"

rule "Rule1:RuleId"
    salience 2147483647
when
    predicate := Predicate(  )  
    (
    eval( policyUtil.evaluate(condition1) ) or
    eval( policyUtil.evaluate(condition2) ) or
    eval( policyUtil.evaluate(condition3) )
then

...

end

rule "defaultRule:defaultRule"
    salience 0
when
    predicate := Predicate(  )  
then

predicate.setValue1("default1");
predicate.setValue2("Default2");
drools.halt();

end
```

This is the after match event trigger:

```
        public void afterMatchFired(AfterMatchFiredEvent event) {
            logger.info("Matching rule Name:: " + event.getMatch().getRule().getName());
            updateHitCountForRule(event.getMatch().getRule().getName());
        }
```

This is how ruledescbuilder is used.

```
        RuleDescrBuilder rdb = pdb.newRule();
        CEDescrBuilder<?, ?> cedb = rdb.lhs();
        cedb = cedb.and();
        for(each condition in rule)
            cedb.eval().constraint(constraint).end();
```

Q: Why is the afterMatchFired triggering multiple times for the same rule with OR conditions? I'm assuming that eval is not being used correctly. If eval is not used correct, what is the right way to build this kind of rule set using the above approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because of the way Drools deals with `or` operator between patterns. What's happening behind the scenes is that Drools creates 3 different rules from your original rule:

```
rule "Rule1:RuleId 1"
salience 2147483647
when
    predicate := Predicate(  )      
    eval( policyUtil.evaluate(condition1) )
then
    ...
end

rule "Rule1:RuleId 2"
salience 2147483647
when
    predicate := Predicate(  )      
    eval( policyUtil.evaluate(condition2) )
then
    ...
end

rule "Rule1:RuleId 3"
salience 2147483647
when
    predicate := Predicate(  )      
    eval( policyUtil.evaluate(condition3) )
then
    ...
end
```

As you can see, there is no short-circuit `or` operator between patterns in Drools. If all of your `eval` match, you will not only receive the `AfterMatchFiredEvent` 3 times, the `action` part of your rule will also be executed 3 times.

One possible way to avoid this (even if it is a little hacky) is to use a fact as a flag to avoid the multiple execution of the `action` part:

```
rule "Rule1:RuleId"
salience 2147483647
when
    not RuleExecuted()
    predicate := Predicate(  )  
    (
        eval( policyUtil.evaluate(condition1) ) or
        eval( policyUtil.evaluate(condition2) ) or
        eval( policyUtil.evaluate(condition3) )
    )
then
    ...
    insert(new RuleExecuted());
end
```

In this scenario, you will still receive 3 `BeforeMatchFiredEvent` events in your listener, but only 1 `AfterMatchFiredEvent`. You will also receive 2 `MatchCancelledEvent` events too.

Hope it helps,

Comment: Thanks Esteban. I executed the OR conditions within a single EVAL in the form of eval( policyUtil.evaluate(condition1) || policyUtil.evaluate(condition2) .. ). This triggered just one event and worked as expected.

Comment: @EstebanAliverti Is this a Drools-specific behavior or any rule engine based on RETE would do the same?